# Can't install Visual Studio Service Pack 1 in my PC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to install VS2010 SP1.

I have tried Using both the [On-Line](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23691) web-installer and [Off-Line](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710) .iso file but I get the below error with either way.

**ERROR MESSAGE I AM GETTING:**
[image]

Does anybody know the cause of this error message?

**EDIT:**

Have a Look at the window comes up when i am go to=> **Help=>About Microsoft Visual Studio**

[image]

Comment: Do you have VS2010 already installed.  SP1 is designed to be installed on top of an existing install (thats what the error is saying).

Comment: ya i have already installed VS2010 Ultimate.

Comment: And does the language of the SP match the language of your VS2010 install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your update I dont believe that SP1 will install on an Release candidate (your vs2010 version is RC1Rel) and you need to get a release version of Visual Studio or one of the  Visual Studio Express Editions.

Comment: Than please tell me what i have to do? thanks for your answer

Comment: You need to purchase a final release version of Visual studio.

Comment: Although I am surprised it still runs as it was supposed to expire in June 2010.  If you dont want to buy a copy of VS2010 Ultimate then you can get the express editions at no charge.

Comment: Yes - SP1 will upgrade express.

Comment: @Lemon, user23012's suggestion will not work i think? isn't it?

Comment: I dont think that would work as it still running the install and you are still running the RC which is supposed to be expired, has no licence and is not intended for continuing use.

Comment: ,,does .iso is available for VS2010 Express? and Silverlight 5 and new feature(XAML debut) will work best with it?? or i have to purchase full version for that?

Comment: So Sorry Leom for miss understanding and miss Spelling......as english is not my first language

Answer (score 1):

it seems there was somone else on the web with your problem anyway heres a fix i saw

> Hi Brian,
>
> Thank you for your post.
>
> From your post, you failed to upgraded Visual Studio 2010.
>
> In my opinion, if you extracted the vstor40_x86.exe from Visual Studio 2010 install media, the vstor40_x86.msi the setup program mentioned is the file which is included in Service Pack 1. Thus I recommend you try to point to the folder “\vstor40\”. Extract vstor40_x86.exe, then point to the vstor40_x86.msi.
>
> If the problem still exists, I recommend you:
>
> ·         Repair your Visual Studio 2010 first.
>
> To do so: Start>>Control Panel>>Uninstall a program>>Choose Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate – ENU>>Uninstall/Change>>Repair/Reinstall.
>
> ·         Download Service Pack 1 ISO file again.
>
> Service Pack 1: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691
>
> In a part of this page “Instructions”, you can see a link of .ISO format.
>
> ·         Extract the ISO file to your local hard disk.
>
> ·         Complete or dismiss Windows Updates before installation (but turn on Windows Update service).
>
> ·         Clean up your “%temp%” folder (Start>>Run>>%temp%).
>
> ·         Check if there are any anti-virus or antispyware applications running. Make sure they are turned off during installation.
>
> ·         Run the setup file with Administrator privileges: Right-click the installer > Run as administrator.
>
> If the problem still exists after these steps, could you please collect the log for me?
>
> ·         Collect the logs from "%temp%" folder with the Log Collection Tool.
>
> Collect tool: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e0da314f-6216-4a18-bc6b-7d29cf83af20&displaylang=en
>
> ·         Send the vslogs.cab file to me (E-mail: v-alsun_at_microsoft_dot_com) or upload it to other website like Windows Live SkyDrive.
>
> If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know.
>
> Best Regards,

i'd link the place i saw it on but i can only post 2 hyperlinks it seems

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vssetup/thread/11ab2527-7600-4bf0-a579-a78c4f86b925  its on this topic

Comment: As Lemon have giving me suggestion this fix will not work for me..isn't it??

Comment: yea itd be better to go with lemons suggestion this one might not work for you

Comment: can we please stop calling me Lemon - its Leom :)

Comment: :) - no problem both - maybe I should change to Lemon - hmmm.